# Push to Twitter from my app used to work - now it doesn't

Tags: twitter

I push a message to Twitter and/or Facebook at the request of the user.

This has been working for months and now it has stopped, for Twitter only.

This is my code:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                           composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:twoatText];

    BOOL weHaveAPhoto = [[passTwoat objectForKey:@"photoSaved"] boolValue];
    if (weHaveAPhoto)
    {
        PFFile *photoFile = [passTwoat objectForKey:@"photo"];
        [photoFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error)
         {
             if (!error)
             {
                 UIImage *fullImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                 [tweetSheet addImage:fullImage];
                 fullImage = nil;
             }
             else
             {
                 [tweetSheet addImage:lclImage];
             }

             [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
         }];
    }
    else
    {
        if (lclImage)
        {
            [tweetSheet addImage:lclImage];
        }
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
        tweetSheet = nil;
        lclImage = nil;
        twoatText = nil;
        passTwoat = nil;
    }
}
```

The 'If' statement fails and so does not execute the push to Twitter. I guess something has changed, and any ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: I solved it.  In Settings Twitter was not allowing my App to send messages to Twitter, so I just changed this and all was fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. In my iPhone Settings, Twitter was not allowing my App to send messages to Twitter, so I just changed this and all was fine.